# How to get sink off of countertop?

Tags: sink, kitchen-counters, removal

We are getting new countertops, and we need to remove the sink before they install them. The sink is attached with a hardened glue.

We can't seem to get the sink off without bending the metal.

How can I get the sink off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First check and make sure that you have removed any fasteners under the counter top holding the sink in place.

Next, you can try wedging a putty knife in between the lip of the sink and the counter and working your way around. Depending on the adhesive used, a solvent like paint thinner may help. A heat gun or hair dryer may also be able to soften the adhesive.

If you're still having trouble, you can always take the sink off with the old counter top and work on it later.

Comment: Yep. heat guns and putty knives work great. So does a Tiger Saw!!

Comment: Doresoom provided good advice. If there is a metal rim around the sink, then there are probably sink rim clips under the counter holding the sink in place.  I seldom replace a  countertop without updating the sink, especially withan old style metal rimmed-sink.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what type of adhesive was used when it was attached, it may not be worth your time to salvage the sink.

In your situation, here is what I would do:

- Shut off the water to the faucet, and disconnect the flexible supply lines.
- Remove the faucet from the sink
- Disconnect the drain line, and plug the open sewer line with a rag
- Using a sawzall (or a circular saw), cut the countertop surrounding the sink.  Leave a couple of inches of countertop connected.
- Remove the sink section from the rest of the countertop, and invert it on a work surface
- Take a small (~2") putty knife, and attempt to slide the knife blade between the sink and the counter.

  - If you can do this, then you may be able to tap the end of the knife with a hammer enough to break the bond.  You can work your way all the way around the top (do not twist the knife, just insert it in the gap and drive it through the glue with the hammer)
- If you can't get the putty knife through, you should be able to break up the bulk of the countertop material (hacksaw, oscillating tool, hammer and chisel, etc.).
- If the last layer of material is still stubborn, you can try to loosen it up with a hair dryer or heat gun.  Failing that, you can get some adhesive solvent from your local home improvement store, and let that work on the joint for a while.  You should be able to eventually work all the material and adhesive off of the sink.

In any case, this is likely not going to be an easy job.  It will be quite time consuming, and you may end up damaging the sink in the process.  You should at least consider replacing the sink as part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

Take Dremel multi tool and run the scrapper attachment around the sink while applying pressur between sink and formica to remove it.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.